# how to take user input, do math to that input, and store the results in an array? in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I feel like there is a better way to do this getOvertones function with an array. Clearly the code takes an input (hz) and then gets the overtone frequencies. I know there must be a more proficient way to do this. Any help is greatly appreciated as I am trying to teach myself.

```
double getOvertones()
{
    double root;
    std::cout << "enter frequency" << '\n';
    std::cin >> root;
    double fundamental = root;
    double second = root * 2.00;
    double third = root * 3.00;
    double fourth = root * 4.00;
    double fifth = root * 5.00;
    std::cout << fundamental << '\n' 
              << second      << '\n' 
              << third       << '\n' 
              << fourth      << '\n' 
              << fifth       << '\n';
    return fundamental;
};
```

I was trying things like:

```
double frequency;
cin >> frequency;

double overtones[5];

for i in overtones...
```

I'm not sure a this point how to fill an array with math results basically.

Comment: It would be useful to see what you hope to do with these frequencies once you compute them: putting them in an array is presumably an implementation detail.

Comment: What have you read in your books, tutorials, or been taught in class? All assignments and exercises should use only material that have been taught or at least mentioned before.

Comment: @DavisHerring I am  wanting this function to return an array with the overtone values if that's possible. And so I can use that data in a separate function, parse the data and print it, etc.

Comment: You can't return C-style arrays. Look into `std::vector` and `std::array`.

Comment: As a potentially different solution, look into structures and classes.

Comment: You don't need an array. It is enough to print the frequencies as you compute them, without storing them anywhere. I recommend doing this first.

Answer (score 0):

```
double getOvertones()
{
    double root;
    double root2;
    std::cout << "enter frequency in hz" << '\n';
    std::cin >> root;

 for (double i = 1; i < 6; i++)
 {
     root2 = root * i;
     std::cout << root2 << '\n';
 }

    return root2;
};
```